# Why "Share Project on Github" (from IntelliJ) works, but "git push remote origin master" (from Terminal) does not?

Tags: git, github, intellij-idea

I forked a project Gradle/Phyton project from Github.

I modified it to be Maven/Java.

I `git remote set-url origin https://github.com/myRepo/myProject.git`

I tried to `git push remote origin master`, and `git push -u remote origin master`

I got `remote: Repository not found.
fatal: repository 'https://github.com/myRepo/myProject.git/' not found`

It did not work.

What worked was to do it from IntelliJ > VCS > Import into Version Control > Share Project On Github.

I believed both ways should work well... Wrong!

Why a Share Project on Github cannot be achieved using terminal commands like 
`git push origin master`?

Does it have to do with the fact that IntelliJ holds Github credentials?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are not pushing properly:

```
git push origin master
```